# Are there similar games to "Love Letter"?

Tags: recommendations, love-letter

We have a group of 5 or so people that enjoy playing [Love Letter](http://www.alderac.com/loveletter/) to fill in a few spare moments at work over lunch or at the end of the day. The key elements are the game is interesting, fast paced, simple rules and not very long to play a round or four.

I'm wondering is there are any similar games out there? Perhaps with a sci-fi theme?

Comment: http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/129622/love-letter You mean this game?

Comment: @user2617804 - Yes, I've added the link.

Comment: @ire_and_curses - Glad to see you you like helping people discover the joys of games. Also you linked meta does nothing to point to any other place to find this information, it's just a few people being all superior saying they really don't want to help the casual player out. Really if all you want is game rule nit-picking questions you'll never get enough movement to get out of Beta. A nice General B&CG Q&A site would be great. This one at the moment is pointless to the masses of casual gamers out there. Also remove the `recommendations` tag sense all recommendations will be closed anyways.

Comment: @Justin808 - I sympathise with your frustration. This meta question explains better the rationale for why these kinds of questions are not allowed: [Should we ban game recommendation questions?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/656/should-we-ban-game-recommendation-questions-done). In a nutshell, there are basically unlimited answers, and they are all opinions. Please understand that this is not personal - the role of a moderator is to enforce the community consensus of the site, that's all.

Comment: @Justin808 - Regarding escaping Beta - Many sites across the SE network have similar prohibitions against generic recommendations. See the linked question above. Their beta status or otherwise is independent of those choices. The [tag:recommendations] tag exists to cover historical questions that we have chosen not to delete. I'm sorry if its existence led you to believe such questions were on-topic.

Comment: @Justin808 - For recommendations, good options are [the boardgames subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/boardgames) or [Board Game Geek](http://www.BoardGamGeek.com). You can also ask in our chat room.

Comment: @Justin808: I understand where you're coming from. As a player, designer, and reviewer of board games, I rarely find occasion to contribute anything to this site. It doesn't upset me, but I guess part of me wishes I had more of a reason to come here :)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 - Its irritating to me, a lot of potentially good SE sites become pointless and unused because of things like this. I would post to meta about it, but you have a minority there who jump down peoples throats for making suggestions they don't already agree with. And SE chat is a joke.

Comment: @Justin808: Lost Legacy ([The Starship](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/158339/lost-legacy-starship),
[Flying Garden](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/158340/lost-legacy-flying-garden),
[Whitegold Spire](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/158341/lost-legacy-whitegold-spire))

Comment: There is a Munchkin-version of this game, it's called Loot Letter. It is *exactly* the same as Love Letter, just with a different theme and therefore different names (and illustrations) for the cards. And I recently saw a Lovecraft Letter which is a more complex further development of Love Letter with additional cards and special effects for when a player turns mad.